# ImagePickerController crashes my app saying "Received Memory Warning" when there are other apps running on my device (2 or more apps)

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, low-memory

My App crashes saying "`Received Memory Warning`" when i take a picture from camera (`UIImagePickerController`).

**Scenario when i get the crash**: If I have other apps running on my device(2 or more), I am getting the crash and if there is only one other app running or no other apps running before I launch my app then there are no crashes at all.

This crash happens only when i take the picture from my camera but when i choose the picture from photo library there is no crash at all.

**I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and I am using ARC**.

Can any one help me on this?

This is the code i am using

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{

    if (buttonIndex < 2) 
    {
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:buttonIndex==0?UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            [ipc setDelegate:(id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>) self];
            [ipc setSourceType:buttonIndex==0?UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
            if (buttonIndex == 0) 
            {
                [ipc setAllowsEditing:NO];
            }
            [ipc setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil]];
            [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
        }
        else 
        {
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Alert" message:@"Camera is not available in this device." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
}



    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        if (!image) image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(scallImage:) toTarget:self withObject:image];
}




 -(void) scallImage:(UIImage *) image
    {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    image=nil;
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSString *cImage = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.5) base64EncodedString];
    [ImageButton setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [ImageButton setHidden:NO];
    //[profileImageButton setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    newImage=nil;
}
```

Is there any thing wrong in my code?

Comment: does this happen after the first picture is displayed or do you have a number of UIImage objects loaded & resident & displayed (e.g. like in a table view)?

Comment: It happens in either ways

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally realized that by removing some of the unwanted images/resources from the project I am able to run my app without crashes ...!!! Thanks everyone who helped me !

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding to allocate UIImagePickerController in that method. Instead allocate it in viewDidLoad. Put this line of code in viewDidLoad:

```
 ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

And have it declared first in .h file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How ever at the end of the method 'ipc' will get released right because I am on ARC

Comment: It will get released after viewDidUnload.

Comment: so if i do "ipc = nil" in the block after my work done then will it release? because i am removing the reference !